# href not working on texlipse

Tags: hyperref, texlipse, hyperlink

I´m trying to add a hyperlink, like this example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{http://google.com}{Google}

\end{document}
```

But I get an error

```
Key http://google.com is undefined
```

Seems like it´s a texlipse problem rather than hyperef, but I don´t know how to solve it, there is another package that I can use to make a hyperlink?